# How can I see generated class files for my Java code in Domino Designer?

Tags: lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

When create Java classes in either Code/Java or by creating folder insider `WebContent\WEB-INF` then the generated class files get stored inside `WebContent\WEB-INF\classes` folder. At least that's what the Java Build Path for my database properties tells me.

[image]

But I am unable to find this folder in my Domino Designer. I checked in Domino Designer and Java perspective under Package Explorer window. It does show up when I click on the "Browse..." button in above picture.

How can I see generated class files for my Java code in Domino Designer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't see them in the Package Explorer. Instead go to the Project Explorer. In the submenu (three horizontal lines above one another) select Customize View... And remove the tick from Java Output Folders resources. You'll then see the class files.

Comment: Thanks Paul! You pointed towards right direction. But in my case it worked when I unchecked `Java output folders`. I am working on 8.5.3.